# Calculate the size of a composite field in a hive table

Tags: hive, archive

In my hive tables (partitioned by date), there's a composite(nested) field. I want to compute its size by summing the byte representation of this field then group by date and sum the bytes. How could I achieve that in hive?

Answer (score 0):

I know how to calculate the size of string representation of the complex object. Maybe this will help you to get some idea at least how to estimate the size in bytes.

Using transform we can get string representation and check the length. [Hive 2.3 has char_length and octet_length](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-15979) if you need UTF-8 character length and the number of UTF-8 octets.

```
with data as (
select array(named_struct('key','value', 'key2', 'тест')) as complex_object
)

select complex_object_str, length(complex_object_str) ascii_length, length(cast(complex_object_str as binary)) binary_length
from 
(
select transform(complex_object) using  '/bin/cat' as complex_object_str from data
)s;
```

Result:

```
complex_object_str  ascii_length    binary_length   
[{"key":"value","key2":"тест"}] 31  35
```